# Cross-Origin Stack Traces

Tags: javascript, html, amazon-s3, cors, cdn

Based on some reading, I've been lead to understand the following:

- Javascript files loaded from a CDN will produced sanitized stack traces in error.stack which contain simply "Script Error"
- Actual traces can be obtained if BOTH the script file includes crossorigin="anonymous" and the CDN sends Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

I have a number of questions about this that I'm hoping someone can answer:

- If I programmatically append a script to the DOM and call script.crossorigin="anonymous" on it first, does that "count"? Will it cause issues on any older browsers?
- Any advice on getting Access-Control headers working with S3 => CloudFlare? It honestly seems impossible. Despite being configured, S3 only sends the headers if the REQUEST includes Origin, which never seems to happen. And even if it did, if the first request came from a browser that doesn't support CORS/Origin headers, the invalid version would be the one that gets cached.
- Is it actually true that I even need these headers? I feel like I've seen stack traces in Chrome without the headers being there. Was the restriction removed from Chrome because it was unrealistic? Or does it not apply to javascript files added programatically? What browser versions actually sanitizes the traces?

Comment: Could you provide the sources of your "reading?"

Comment: Absolutely. Here's a good one: https://errorception.com/docs/cors  Thanks for making me re-read that. I now realize why I'm seeing stack traces without CORS in place. Per that link, it's only the stack traces in window.onerror that are suppressed when CORS is missing. Errors thrown and caught within a CDN script itself aren't subject to CORS restrictions.  Since that's the bulk of my use case, I may be ok without CORS headers. I'd still be interested to hear if anyone has succeeded in getting them working with S3 => CloudFlare as I wasn't able to.

Comment: i don't think the trace is fully censored, but it might omit line numbers in window.onerror-tyle global error handlers.